# How do I decode a string with Decode

Tags: c#, urldecode

My database stores the following value

```
a%0Ab%0Ac
```

I'm trying to decode this as the %0A represents a new line

When I use javascript, I can use DecodeUri() and it works fine but I'm trying to get this to work with C#

The following make no difference to the string

```
 @Server.HtmlDecode(item.Detail)  
 @System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Detail)
 @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Detail)
```

Using all of these shows

```
a%0Ab%0Ac
```

I'm hoping to achieve the following from within my view using Razor

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: You are trying to display a b c values inside a view ?

Comment: yes @dbraillon, within the cshtml file.

Comment: Looks like you need the one you didn't try: `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` Html Entities are encoded like this: `&#13;` [More Info here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, this is kinda there... I no longer have the encoding but it doesn't display as different lines as if <br /> was used

Comment: Then add it, can be naive but... html can't display line returns right ?

Comment: Well, of course not. It is stored URL encoded and you need it HTML encoded. A direct conversion would be nonsense, so you need to URL DE-code it (whyever it is encoded in the database in the first place, it shouldn't be) and then HTML EN-code it.

Comment: Btw: the `a%0` does **not** represent a new line, `%0A` does.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, your comment is great and I've done additional research (that isn't sarcasm, I'm genuinely grateful). However, I'm unclear as what approach I could take. I'm saving the value of a TextArea where the user can press return to create new lines. This value needs to be saved into a database so when I read it out, it shows exactly as they entered it. If I don't Encode it, how else can I achieve this?

Comment: Make sure your database uses unicode (which is a kind of encoding of course, but not URL or HTML encoded) and save the values in your database exactly as you get them. If you get them encoded, make sure to decode them first (into a "neutral" format). When you use the value (display it in html) encode in in the appropriate format. Further advice: ignore all answers that contain a call to `Replace` - there are existing functions that do all that in a complete and reliable way (e.g. HttpUtility)

Answer (score 1):

You can decode `%0A` using `UrlDecode` method of `HttpUtility`. Then you can replace new line with your customized line break(in your case, html break tag)

```
string decodeValue =  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input).Replace("\n", "<br>");
```

Comment: OR [use the proper HTML encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx) and take care of other special characters too...

Answer (score 0):

Naive answer, but it works !

```
@{ 
    var toDecode = "a%0Ab%0Ac";
    var decoded = toDecode.Replace("%0A", "<br>");

    @Html.Raw(decoded)
}
```

Comment: Probably too naive answer :(